# Return data when inserting a list with executeBatch()

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have to access the automatically generated data (id, created, last_modified ...) when inserting data lists. Because the lists may be large, I use `statement.executeBatch()` to add everything in a package. However, this way I lose the opportunity to take advantage of the `returning` statement.

I am currently doing the following to get the data:

```
public boolean store(Connection connection, List<WorkPlace> list) throws SQLException {
    String query =
            "insert into work_places (merchant_id, name, description) values (?, ?, ?)";

    try(PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
        for(WorkPlace workPlace: list) {
            statement.setLong(1, workPlace.getMerchantId());
            statement.setString(2, workPlace.getName());
            statement.setString(3, workPlace.getDescription());

            statement.addBatch();
        }

        statement.executeBatch();

        try(ResultSet rs = statement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
            List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();

            while (rs.next()) {
                ids.add(rs.getLong(1));
            }

            query =
                    "select * from work_places where id = any (?)";

            try(PreparedStatement statement1 = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
                statement1.setArray(1, connection.createArrayOf("integer", ids.toArray()));

                try(ResultSet rs1 = statement1.executeQuery()) {
                    list.clear();

                    while (rs1.next()) {
                        list.add(getWorkPlace(rs1));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Are you interested, is there a better way to achieve what I need?

Comment: You can use https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/AbstractJdbcInsert.html#doExecuteAndReturnKeyHolder-java.util.Map and work on keys with a simple select query,

Comment: _"However, this way I lose the opportunity to take advantage of the returning statement."_. Exactly what is the problem? The generated keys implementation in the PostgreSQL JDBC driver uses `RETURNING *`, so if you can retrieve the generated id this way after executing a batch, then you should also be able to retrieve the other columns from the same `getGeneratedKeys` result set.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, your comment was extremely helpful. Please run it as an answer so I can rate it.

Comment: Good to hear. I initially posted it as a comment, as I did not have the time to actually test and verify if it would really work. I now posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated keys implementation in the PostgreSQL JDBC driver uses `RETURNING *`, which will return all columns from the table. So, if you can retrieve the generated id this way after executing a batch, then you should also be able to retrieve the other columns from the same `getGeneratedKeys` result set.

Comment: You helped me a lot. I do not know at all that I can use `getGeneratedKeys()` this way.

Comment: @mrmcwolf Be aware, this is driver specific. Not all JDBC driver return all columns in the generated keys result set (some will return only the primary key, some only 'generated' columns (eg identity, default values, computed columns)), and support for generated-keys in batch execution is not required by the JDBC specification.